Characteristic Polynomials for AR(p) Processes with intercepts
If we have AR(1) process with no intercept like:
$$
x_t=\phi x_{t-1}+w_t,
$$
it has a unit root when $|\phi|=1$.
If we have an AR(p) process with no constant
$$
x_t=\phi_1 x_{t-1}+\phi_2 x_{t-2}+\cdots+\phi_p x_{t-p}+w_t, 
$$
its characteristic polynomial is defined as
$$
\phi(B)=1-\phi_1 B-\phi_2 B^2-\ldots-\phi_p B^p.
$$
So for AR(p), this characteristic polynomial needs to have a root of 1 or -1.
My question is, if we have a constant term $c$ (such as below), is the “characteristic polynomial” the same as above, and we just look at that same characteristic polynomial to figure out the unit roots (or in the case of AR(1), look at $|\phi|$)?
$$x_t=\phi x_{t-1}+w_t +c$$
$$x_t=\phi_1 x_{t-1}+\phi_2 x_{t-2}+\cdots+\phi_p x_{t-p}+w_t+c$$

The constant only shifts the level of the process but has no effect on its stationarity or the roots the characteristic polynomial. The characteristic polynomial is the same regardless of the presence/absence of the constant.
